# MVC calling another controller's action from another controller's action

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Let's imagine that we have `OrderController` controller with three actions/pages: `orderDetailsAction`, `orderHistoryAction`, `orderCustomerDetailsAction`

Each of these actions are returning some piece of HTML.

Now I want to have page containing all 3 html pieces in same time, *but I don't want to make 3 ajax calls to get this done*.

I'm creating additional controller's action method (`orderSummaryAction`, for example). This method should contain something like this.

```
public function orderSummartyAction {
   ob_start();
   Application::factory()->run('/order/details');
   Application::factory()->run('/order/history');
   Application::factory()->run('/order/customer_details');     
   $out = ob_get_clean();
   $this->getResponse()->setHtml($out);
}
```

Is there any framework doing such things or maybe it is bad practice (what is better practice then)?

Thank you!

UPD: Or we can pass not string url, but Route to create new Application instance. It would be much better, imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony2 uses sub-request to invoke multiple controllers.
You can find more details under 'Embedding Controllers' here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not very familiar with Symfony2. Where should I take look at to find out how Symofony executes this Twig directive `{% render "AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentArticles" with {'max': 3} %}`? Thank you!

Comment: It uses a helper (https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/master/Templating/Helper/ActionsHelper.php) that calls the function 'render' of the kernel (https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/master/HttpKernel.php)

Comment: Aha, I found this test as well https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/TokenParser/RenderTokenParser.php

Answer (score 1):

I would say , that the cause of your problem is invalid MVC implementation.

It is not the *controller*'s responsibility to generate HTML. Instead, the output should be created by *view* instance -  an object which deals with presentation logic and juggles with multiple templates. Contrary to what RoR has been trying to feed us - **view is not a template**.

In proper MVC, controller's are responsible for changing state of *model layer* and selected *view*, based either directly on user input or some sort of `Request` instance.

Also, two **side note**:

- please, do not use *factory method pattern* <sup>[[1]](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FactoryMethodPattern) [[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)</sup>. IMHO, this is an antipattern, because it causes tight coupling between classes and attracts complexity (they tend to grow uncontrollably).
- it might be useful, instead of returning large blocks of HTML, respond to XHR call with data in JSON format. And then generate the HTML on the client-side.